# Microsoft Terminal Server blocks flash content

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, internet-explorer, flash, windows-terminal-services

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise server running, where users are unable to use sites such as YouSendIt to transfer large files out of their own organization.

The server also runs Internet Explorer 9, with the latest Flash 10.3.181.34 installed.

The flash element used is loaded (I can right click and select the About Flash option), but it is unable to load the file uploading tool it self. I suspect it's a permissions issue, but I am not sure what permission this is related to. I am able to load sites such as YouTube without any problems, and the official flash website can load flash content and tells me it is installed and working as it should.

I've attempted adding the site Trusted Sites in IE, I have also lowered the security settings, allowed ActiveX components as well.

Comment: Out of intrest, why are you using a Windows server to browse the internet? Lowering the security settings is probably a bad idea too, if you get any badware on your server, there's a chance it could get out to other clients connected to the server.

Comment: It is running as a Terminal Server, which is why it's being used to access internet sites as well.

Comment: #Facepalm Yeah I can read, makes sense. I still wouldn't advise lowering the security settings but I believe Flash runs in a sort of security sandbox which might be blocking the file loader. Have you had a chance to check other browsers (Say Chrome or FF) to find out if it's Flash or IE (If it works in other browsers it's n IE problem/setting, if not it's ether a flash or an OS thing)

Comment: Yes, it works fine in FireFox (and testing in Chrome is moot as Chrome bundles Flash with it's sandbox modes). Hence I am back with IE and the suspicion it's a permissions issue.

Comment: Are you using a proxy server? We have the same type of issues with using flash to upload (prezi and issuu) and after speaking to our support people (smoothwall) it seems to be a problem with passing credentials. (and it only seems to affect IE)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a silly question, but are you certain you are using the 32 bit version of IE?  The 64 bit version is severely lacking.

The 64 bit version of IE doesn't run most browser plugins.  The 64 bit version does not use the newer faster javascript engine.